# Codeigniter best practice: make sense use helper for common function managing DB?

Tags: database, codeigniter, helper

I need to define common functions for managing a mySQL DB: updating, inserting, deleting functions to be used in several different pages of the WEB site. Since generally the access to DB is defined in models, I wonder if in case of common functions managing a DB it is possible and makes sense to define them in helper instead in a model of a  specific page.

Answer (score 1):

Those functions shouldn't be in a helper but in a extension of your CI_Model.

You can create a new class in your application/core folder and create a MY_Model.php file.

That class should extend to your CI_Model. Then all your models will extend to MY_Model instead of CI_Model.

If you're looking to automate that kind of crud functionality you might want to look into something like this that has everything you need and more:

[Codeigniter MY Model](https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model)

This is a deprecated model, but you can check what can be done or even clone it and maintain it yourself.

Comment: thanks marco; so if I well understood the best practice is to create anyway a file containing just common functions accessing the DB, not related to a specific page, but still in the model folder. Isn't it?

Comment: A model file should represent a part of your business model logic. Imagine you are processing invoices all your functions that interact with your invoice tables should be there. But same with all the extra functions that you might need to calc stuff related to that part of the business. Not just database interaction. You should try to have a base model class that has all the logic that might be used by all your models.Helpers are for small functions you need on certain situations. ie. transform a string and just output the 1st 10 chars. You create a function to take care of that in a helper.